# sharing virtual address space with malloc

Tags: android, ios, linux, windows, macos

I'm writing a custom memory allocation routine intended to either replace malloc(), or to live alongside of malloc() peacefully, with different memory allocators being called under different circumstances.

Now, different memory allocation routines make different demands on the virtual address space. With a free list you can basically just keep asking the OS for more memory pages with mmap(), one memory page at a time. You can throw your data into those pages at will, even if those pages are scattered around all over the virtual address space, because you can link your pages together with pointer metadata. On the other hand, something like a buddy allocator can't just add pages to itself at will. Buddy allocators need to have big slabs of virtual memory space with no holes.

So, my question is this: How does malloc() make use of virtual memory space? Different implementations probably differ, but I'm interested in answers in the context of any of the usual ones: OS X, Windows, Linux, the various BSDs, iOS, and Android.

If I'm running on a 32-bit machine, and I ask mmap() for 3gigs of contiguous memory space for something like a custom buddy allocator, then is malloc() likely to get upset? Does malloc() do something similar? In general, how does one make one's own mmap() code behave as a good citizen in the virtual address space? Or is it just the wild west out there?

Comment: The mobile platforms (iOS and Android) don't have page files. They will fail if you try to malloc for 3GB, considering some of those devices only have 256MB or 512MB of RAM.